# Function with variable parameter size: How to conditionally set some arguments?

Tags: c++, boost

To create a boost::process with output redirection, you should do:

```
bp::ipstream out;
bp::child c("c++filt", std_out > out);
```

Now, what would be the syntax to conditionally control the redirection:

```
bool redirect = true; // or false
bp::ipstream out;
bp::child c("c++filt", (redirect) ? std_out > out : "what should I put here??" );
```

Comment: You still have the possibility: `auto c = redirect ? bp::child("c++filt", std_out > out) : bp::child("c++filt");`

Comment: That's what I'm doing today, but as I also need to conditionnaly set other options (like `::boost::process::windows::show` or `::boost::process::windows::hide` based on another boolean), it will end up very messy...

Comment: You can then create factory function.

Comment: @Jarod42:Would this avoid having n^2 versions of the constructor call if I have n input booleans? Could you link to/post an example of how this could be achieved?

Comment: I just did, /cc @Jarod42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fancy `boost::process` API revolves around supplying `handler` objects implementing `on_setup`, `on_error`, `on_success` (and potentially some more, depending on current OS) methods that will be executed at process construction call in context of some internal process launcher and will be able to alter process launcher behavior. `std_out > out` is an overloaded operator that will return such handler. More information can be found at [boost process Extensions documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_process/extend.html).

So the generic way to conditionally control the redirection and other parameters would be to write generic handler proxy accepting optional real handler and calling appropriate methods of real handler:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/extend.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<typename TRealHandler> class
t_OptionalHandler
:    public ::boost::process::extend::handler
{
    private: using t_OptionalRealHandler = ::boost::optional<TRealHandler>;

    private: t_OptionalRealHandler m_real_handler;

    public:
    t_OptionalHandler(void)
    :   m_real_handler{}
    {}

    public: explicit
    t_OptionalHandler(TRealHandler && real_handler)
    :   m_real_handler{::std::move(real_handler)}
    {}

    template<typename TExecutor>
    void on_setup(TExecutor & e) const
    {
        if(m_real_handler)
        {
            m_real_handler.get().on_setup(e);
        }
    }

    template<typename TExecutor>
    void on_error(TExecutor & e, const std::error_code & code) const
    {
        if(m_real_handler)
        {
            m_real_handler.get().on_error(e, code);
        }
    }

    template<typename TExecutor>
    void on_success(TExecutor & e) const
    {
        if(m_real_handler)
        {
            m_real_handler.get().on_success(e);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool const need_to_redirect{false};
    ::std::unique_ptr<::boost::process::ipstream> const p_stream
    {
        need_to_redirect?
        new ::boost::process::ipstream{}
        :
        nullptr
    };
    using t_OptionalStdOutRedirectionHandler = t_OptionalHandler
    <
        decltype(::boost::process::std_out > *p_stream)
     >;
    ::boost::process::child ch
    (
        "cmd"
    ,   need_to_redirect?
        t_OptionalStdOutRedirectionHandler{::boost::process::std_out > *p_stream}
        :
        t_OptionalStdOutRedirectionHandler{}
    );
    ch.wait();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. The naming is a huge hurdle here. `t_OptionalStdOutRedirectionHandler` is too ugly for my taste (I suppose a `optionally(...)` factory function would do). Also, there's meta-programming that does make decisions based on the presence/absense of particular keyword arguments, so things might not work identically. In such cases, the library should probably be modified to use a trait that can also be specialized for your wrapper keyword. +1

Comment: Really? It's just crazy you have to write so many lines of code and be such an expert in meta-programming just to conditionnaly set a parameter to a function call. But it works like a charm (even if I must admit I don't fully understand how it does ;-))!

Comment: @VTT: g++ complains `error: could not convert 'need_to_redirect' from 'const std::initializer_list<const bool>' to 'bool'
                 ::std::unique_ptr<::boost::process::ipstream>{}` inside p_stream definition for `std::unique_ptr<::boost::process::ipstream>{}`....any idea what would be the correct syntax? (tried to use `std::unique_ptr<::boost::process::ipstream>()` instead of `{}` but it gives the same error...

Comment: @jpo38 And which version of g++ outputs it? This code example should [work fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZRSRWgZSbL6QJfW3).

Comment: @VTT: gcc 4.9 for Android (ndk r11b)

Comment: @jpo38 You can replace first line with `bool const need_to_redirect{false};`.

Comment: @jpo38 Turs out that gcc 4.9 does not have support for `make_unique` yet. So [a bit of additional refactoring will help](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cK6BnC1JRwhS8ECP).

Comment: @VTT: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your precious help, this almost deserves a new upvote!

Comment: @VTT: Updated your post with this new version for the record!

Answer (score 1):

I've been there.

Indeed, launcher functions (not exactly factories, but composable procedural wrappers) were what I used.

### Intro

We had a CommandRunner with a legacy implementation that I rewrote to use Boost. I'm skipping the public interface:

```
class CommandRunner {
    public: struct IRunnerImpl;
};
```

The implementation was Pimpl-ed and worked with the base implementation storing mostly simple implementation-independent parameters:

```
struct CommandRunner::IRunnerImpl {
    virtual ~IRunnerImpl() = default;

    virtual void run()                    = 0;
    virtual void ensure_completed()       = 0;
    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;

    friend class CommandRunner;
  protected:
    std::string            _working_directory;
    mylibrary::optional<mylibrary::io::time::duration> _time_constraint;
    std::string            _stdin_data;
    int                    _redirected_output_fd     = -1;
    std::string            _redirected_output_fname;
    bool                   _discard_output           = false;
    int                    _exit_code;
    std::string            _stdout_str;
    std::string            _stderr_str;
    bool                   _command_timed_out        = false;
    bool                   _sensitive_args           = false;
    string_map_t           _env;
};
```

### The Boost RunnerImpl

The core of `ensure_completed` was composed using helper lambdas like this:

```
try {
    mylibrary::threads::safe_io_service safe_ios;
    boost::asio::io_service& ios = safe_ios;
    mylibrary::io::time::timer deadline(ios);

    bp::group process_group;

    bp::async_pipe input(ios);
    std::future<std::string> output, error;

    if (_working_directory.empty())
        _working_directory = ".";

    auto on_exit = [this, &deadline](int exit, std::error_code ec) {
        if (!_command_timed_out) {
            _exit_code = exit;
        }
        deadline.cancel();
        if (ec) s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Child process returned " << ec.message();
        else    s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG)   << "Child process returned";
    };

    auto launcher = [](auto&&... args) { return bp::child(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args).../*, bp::posix::fd.restrict_inherit()*/); };

    auto redirect_out = [&](auto f) {
        return [&,f](auto&&... args) {
            if (_discard_output) {
                if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
                    s_logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "Ignoring output redirection with set_discard_output. This is a bug.";
                }
                return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > bp::null, bp::std_err > bp::null);
            }

            if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
                s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Conflicting output redirection, ignoring filename with descriptor";
            }

            if (_redirected_output_fd != -1) {
                return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::posix::fd.bind(1, _redirected_output_fd), bp::std_err > error);
            }

            return _redirected_output_fname.empty()
                ? f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > output,                   bp::std_err > error)
                : f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > _redirected_output_fname, bp::std_err > error);
        };
    };

    bp::environment bp_env = boost::this_process::environment();
    for (auto& p : _env)
        bp_env[p.first] = p.second;

    auto c = redirect_out(launcher)(_command_path, _args,
            process_group,
            bp::std_in < input,
            bp::start_dir(_working_directory),
            bp_env,
            ios, bp::on_exit(on_exit)
        );

    if (_time_constraint) {
        deadline.expires_from_now(*_time_constraint);
        deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                if (ec) {
                    s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Unexpected condition in CommandRunner deadline: " << ec.message();
                }

                _command_timed_out = true;
                _exit_code = 1;
                ::killpg(process_group.native_handle(), SIGTERM);

                deadline.expires_from_now(3s); // grace time
                deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) { if (!ec) process_group.terminate(); }); // timed out
            }
        });
    }

    boost::asio::async_write(input, bp::buffer(_stdin_data), [&input](auto ec, auto bytes_written){
        if (ec) {
            s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Standard input rejected: " << ec.message() << " after " << bytes_written << " bytes written";
        }
        may_fail([&] { input.close(); });
    });

    ios.run();

    if (output.valid()) _stdout_str = output.get();
    if (error.valid())  _stderr_str = error.get();

    // make sure no grand children survive
    if (process_group && process_group.joinable() && !process_group.wait_for(1s))
        process_group.terminate();

    // Note: even kills get the child reaped; 'on_exit' handler is
    // actually the 'on wait_pid() complete'). No need for c.wait()
    // in this scenario
    //// may_fail([&] { if (c.running()) c.wait(); }); // to avoid zombies
} catch(bp::process_error const& e) {
    if (e.code().value() != static_cast<int>(std::errc::no_child_process)) throw;
}
```

### Full Self-Contained Listing

This compiles, but doesn't have any public interface. Merely for expositional purposes.

Note:

- this didn't go into production as there were cases in which the Boost implementation would get stuck in async IO operations. The reason for this has remained unclear, but I suspect it is a hairy case of [`epoll` is fundamentally broken](https://idea.popcount.org/2017-03-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-22/) related to our use cases being "wildly" multi-threaded and forking.
- this does not include our attempted workarounds for `safe_io_service` (that guarantees fork synchronization and notifications on all active io_services)
- this does not include our patch that adds restricted FD inheritance:

  ```
  auto launcher = [](auto&&... args) { return 
       bp::child(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., 
       bp::posix::fd.restrict_inherit()); };
  ```
- other crucial things like on-fork handlers for global (library) state have not been shown here (they used `pthread_atfork` and similar)

**<kbd>[Compiling On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50bc64196b7d12cd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/extend.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <boost/process/posix.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <signal.h> // ::killpg
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

///////
// mockups for standalone exposition
//#include "log.h"
enum LOG_LEVELS{LOG_DEBUG, LOG_WARNING, LOG_ERR};

struct DummyLogger {
    struct Tx {
        template <typename...Ts> friend Tx operator<<(Tx const&, Ts&&...) { return {}; }
    };
    Tx log(LOG_LEVELS) { return {}; }
} s_logger;

//#include "safe_io_service.h"
namespace mylibrary { 
    namespace threads {
        //this did manage fork notifications
        using safe_io_service = boost::asio::io_service;
    } 
    using boost::optional;
    namespace io { namespace time {
            using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
            using duration = clock::duration;
            using timer = boost::asio::high_resolution_timer;
        }
    }
}
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using string_vector_t = std::vector<std::string>;
using string_map_t = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

class CommandRunner {
    public: struct IRunnerImpl;
};

struct CommandRunner::IRunnerImpl {
    virtual ~IRunnerImpl() = default;

    virtual void run()                    = 0;
    virtual void ensure_completed()       = 0;
    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;

    friend class CommandRunner;
  protected:
    std::string            _working_directory;
    mylibrary::optional<mylibrary::io::time::duration> _time_constraint;
    std::string            _stdin_data;
    int                    _redirected_output_fd     = -1;
    std::string            _redirected_output_fname;
    bool                   _discard_output           = false;
    int                    _exit_code;
    std::string            _stdout_str;
    std::string            _stderr_str;
    bool                   _command_timed_out        = false;
    bool                   _sensitive_args           = false;
    string_map_t           _env;
};

//
//////////////////////////////////////

namespace {

    namespace bp = boost::process;

    template <typename F> static auto may_fail(F&& f) {
        try {
            return std::forward<F>(f)();
        } catch(std::exception const& e) {
            s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG) << "Ignoring non-fatal error (" << e.what() << ")";
        } catch(...) {
            s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG) << "Ignoring non-fatal, unspecified error";
        }
    }

}

namespace mylibrary { namespace process { namespace with_boost {

    struct BoostRunnerImpl : CommandRunner::IRunnerImpl {

        BoostRunnerImpl(std::string cmd_path, string_vector_t args) :
            _command_path(std::move(cmd_path)),
            _args(std::move(args))
        {
        }

        std::string _command_path;
        string_vector_t _args;

        virtual void run() override {
            if (_completed) {
                s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG) << "NOT running already completed command: " << *this;
                return;
            }
            ensure_completed();
        }

        ////////////////////////////
        // implementation
        virtual void ensure_completed() override {
            if (_completed) return;

            // Log command and args
            s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG) << "Running command: " << *this;

            try {
                try {
                    mylibrary::threads::safe_io_service safe_ios;
                    boost::asio::io_service& ios = safe_ios;
                    mylibrary::io::time::timer deadline(ios);

                    bp::group process_group;

                    bp::async_pipe input(ios);
                    std::future<std::string> output, error;

                    if (_working_directory.empty())
                        _working_directory = ".";

                    auto on_exit = [this, &deadline](int exit, std::error_code ec) {
                        if (!_command_timed_out) {
                            _exit_code = exit;
                        }
                        deadline.cancel();
                        if (ec) s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Child process returned " << ec.message();
                        else    s_logger.log(LOG_DEBUG)   << "Child process returned";
                    };

                    auto launcher = [](auto&&... args) { return bp::child(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args).../*, bp::posix::fd.restrict_inherit()*/); };

                    auto redirect_out = [&](auto f) {
                        return [&,f](auto&&... args) {
                            if (_discard_output) {
                                if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
                                    s_logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "Ignoring output redirection with set_discard_output. This is a bug.";
                                }
                                return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > bp::null, bp::std_err > bp::null);
                            }

                            if (_redirected_output_fd != -1 && !_redirected_output_fname.empty()) {
                                s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Conflicting output redirection, ignoring filename with descriptor";
                            }

                            if (_redirected_output_fd != -1) {
                                return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::posix::fd.bind(1, _redirected_output_fd), bp::std_err > error);
                            }

                            return _redirected_output_fname.empty()
                                ? f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > output,                   bp::std_err > error)
                                : f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bp::std_out > _redirected_output_fname, bp::std_err > error);
                        };
                    };

                    bp::environment bp_env = boost::this_process::environment();
                    for (auto& p : _env)
                        bp_env[p.first] = p.second;

                    auto c = redirect_out(launcher)(_command_path, _args,
                            process_group,
                            bp::std_in < input,
                            bp::start_dir(_working_directory),
                            bp_env,
                            ios, bp::on_exit(on_exit)
                        );

                    if (_time_constraint) {
                        deadline.expires_from_now(*_time_constraint);
                        deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                            if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                                if (ec) {
                                    s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Unexpected condition in CommandRunner deadline: " << ec.message();
                                }

                                _command_timed_out = true;
                                _exit_code = 1;
                                ::killpg(process_group.native_handle(), SIGTERM);

                                deadline.expires_from_now(3s); // grace time
                                deadline.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec) { if (!ec) process_group.terminate(); }); // timed out
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    boost::asio::async_write(input, bp::buffer(_stdin_data), [&input](auto ec, auto bytes_written){
                        if (ec) {
                            s_logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Standard input rejected: " << ec.message() << " after " << bytes_written << " bytes written";
                        }
                        may_fail([&] { input.close(); });
                    });

                    ios.run();

                    if (output.valid()) _stdout_str = output.get();
                    if (error.valid())  _stderr_str = error.get();

                    // make sure no grand children survive
                    if (process_group && process_group.joinable() && !process_group.wait_for(1s))
                        process_group.terminate();

                    // Note: even kills get the child reaped; 'on_exit' handler is
                    // actually the 'on wait_pid() complete'). No need for c.wait()
                    // in this scenario
                    //// may_fail([&] { if (c.running()) c.wait(); }); // to avoid zombies
                } catch(bp::process_error const& e) {
                    if (e.code().value() != static_cast<int>(std::errc::no_child_process)) throw;
                }
            } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                s_logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "CommandRunner: " << e.what();
                _completed = true;
                _exit_code = 1;
                throw;
            } catch(...) {
                s_logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "CommandRunner: unexpected error";
                _completed = true;
                _exit_code = 1;
                throw;
            }

            _completed = true;
        }

      private:
        bool _completed = false;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BoostRunnerImpl const& i) {
            os << i._command_path;
            if (i._sensitive_args)
                os << " (" << i._args.size() << " args)";
            else for (auto& arg : i._args)
                os << " " << std::quoted(arg);
            return os;
        }

        virtual std::string to_string() const override {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << *this;
            return oss.str();
        }
    };

} } }

int main(){}
```

Comment: And there is really no easier way to switch between two list of arguments? ;-) Honestly, I was not expecting to have to compile so many lines of code for such a simple question....

Comment: This was just to show what we did, being examples of what the other commenters suggested. In the end, it confirms your suspicion: the focus on a typed compile-time generic results in an awkward API for dynamic use. Nothing new, for Boost. The thing that perplexed me the most is that no one realised that the "performance win" is irrelevant as soon as external processes are being started.