# Boost process open process in new window (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, multiprocessing, boost-process

I'm trying to design a program that uses workers processes - which are just a different program written in C++.

I start a worker process like so:

```
auto worker = boost::process::child("./worker.exe");
worker->detach();
```

The issue is, is that the worker processes are outputting information to the same command line window that they are spawned from. This is cluttering the output of the program. Ideally I want each process to run in its own window.

Is this possible using boost::process? I've only found information about hiding the window.

I'm using Windows and Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [Boost::process hide console on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43583001/1539100), you can create new mode for creating process.

[CreateProcessA function system call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), Show yourself to how to create new process with new console, by helping creation flags: `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` (thanks to [Using multiple console windows for output](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/195157/28682))

you can write code like below

```cpp
struct new_window
:   ::boost::process::detail::handler_base
{
    // this function will be invoked at child process constructor before spawning process
    template <class WindowsExecutor>
    void on_setup(WindowsExecutor &e) const
    {
        e.creation_flags = ::boost::detail::winapi::CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE_;
    }
};
```

and for using this, you can just write something like below

```cpp
::boost::process::child ch("./worker.exe", new_window);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What are the #includes to get this working?

Comment: Never mind, it was #include <boost/detail/winapi/process.hpp>

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked great! As a bonus could you tell me what the env argument is for? It works perfectly fine without it in my application.

Comment: It is not important, I just explicitly specify process environment. (I delete it, to minimalize answer)

Comment: what dies INTOA mean?