# Boost::process hide console on linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, gtkmm, avaloniaui

According to this question : [Boost::process hide console on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582022/boostprocess-hide-console-on-windows)

How can I achieve the same but on Linux platform using boost::process ? (prevent console window creation on the newly spawn child process)

My use case is as followed:

I'm trying to call a cross-platform GUI app built from .NET 5.0 AvaloniaUI (C#). And I'm calling that from another GUI app built from gtkmm (c++). **It does create black console along with GUI window.**

This symptom doesn't occur when I tried calling the same mentioned Avalonia app with another cross-platform Avalonia app. It doesn't create any console, only the GUI window as intended. (Using System.Diagnostics.Process from .NET C#).

So maybe there is some detail behind that make these api behave differently? (boost::process / System.Diagnostics.Process)

Basically I'm looking for the api to do the same thing with System.Diagnostics.Process (C#) on c++

Comment: What symptoms are you trying to fix? Starting a process with `boost::process` on a posix system should not create any "console" - unless the program you start is actually creating it.

Comment: I'm trying to call a cross-platform GUI app built from .NET 5.0 (AvaloniaUI C#) and Im calling that from another GUI app built from gtkmm (c++). It creates black console along with GUI window.

In another case, I tried calling the same mentioned .NET app with another cross-platform Avalonia app, and it doesn't create any console, only GUI window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux does not create new console, like the others suggested.** (unless explicitly define to)

After more investigation, I found that, it's only a misunderstanding.

If you use some GUI lib (like GTKmm, in this case), and try to spawn new process, which is a GUI window also, **there might be an afterimage-like effect if you don't do it asynchonously**

(If that second GUI window is initialized with *black* background, like the one created with AvaloniaUI, you may confuse it as another console :p)

Answer (score 0):

On linux a new console isn't created anyways. So, the only thing you might want to do is prevent the child process from sharing the parent's, like so:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::process;
int main() {
    bp::child child(bp::search_path("xclock"), //
                    bp::std_in.null(),         //
                    bp::std_out.null(),        //
                    bp::std_err.null());

    child.wait();
}
```

If, on the other hand, you would *like* to create a terminal, you have to tell the OS which one you want and how to start that:

```
bp::child child(bp::search_path("gnome-terminal"),  //
                std::vector<std::string>{"-x", "/usr/bin/htop"}, //
                bp::std_in.null(),                  //
                bp::std_out.null(),                 //
                bp::std_err.null());
```

Or, e.g.

```
bp::child child(bp::search_path("gnome-terminal"),  //
                std::vector<std::string>{"-x", "/usr/bin/htop"}, //
                bp::std_in.null(),                  //
                bp::std_out.null(),                 //
                bp::std_err.null());
```

Note that the `gnome-terminal` launcher forks (so it "returns" immediately, leaving the terminal running with the `htop` inside), but `xterm` does not. So, on UNIX, like ever, you have lots of choices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My use case is a bit different, as I have commented on the question, I'm calling a cross-platform app built with .NET AvaloniaUI and it does create a black console along with GUI window. This symtoms doesn't occur when I call it from another cross-platform app.

Comment: "You call it from another cross-platform app"? What does that mean? How does that do it? Why don't you do it in the same way?

Comment: By the way, if yours is a .NET core app, than simply make it a GUI binary, not a Console application. Windows distinguishes those, so likely as well for .NET core assemblies

Comment: Also, have you tried my code? It's not unthinkable that `dotnet` will detect the absence of input/output streams and respond to that.

Comment: In fact, I just [created a simple Console assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet#examples) and then ran it with http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3ed064e41d54a9d - it didn't create a console/terminal window, not even when ran without terminal (via `at` or `nohup`). You'll have to debug what is different, and perhaps find the option that prevents .NET from creating the console.

Comment: Yes, perhaps this is more related with the UI framework I use with it (Avalonia).
[(their website)](https://avaloniaui.net/)

Comment: I think the problem may lie within how the System.Diagnostic.Process of C# .NET do thing differently than boost::process

Maybe .NET would create console explicitly if some arg hasn't been passed from the caller (which in the problem case, is boost::process)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243364/discussion-between-porameth-kaptaphol-and-sehe).